# error on adding if else statement inside trigger mysql

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers

I am new to triggers in mysql and found them really useful. I want a help regarding the trigger i am creating. First, I created a trigger on update event as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_mytable_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `my_table`
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.total_pts=NEW.pts_1+NEW.pts_2+NEW.pts_3, 
NEW.old_pts=OLD.total_pts
```

It worked fine. Now, I need to add an if/else inside my trigger. So, I dropped and recreated trigger as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `after_mytable_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `my_table`
FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.total_pts=NEW.pts_1+NEW.pts_2+NEW.pts_3, 
NEW.old_pts=OLD.total_pts;
IF (NEW.total_pts>=0) THEN
 UPDATE 'my_table' SET NEW.level='my_value';
END IF;
```

But it is giving error #1064. I need to set `total_pts` value outside if/else statement, but I am new to triggers and cannot figure out my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trigger syntax is not correct, you are missing the `begin`, it should be as below. Also you are missing `delimiter`. Also your trigger is `before update` so you do not need to have the update command inside the trigger again. You can just set the value for the column.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER `after_mytable_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `my_table`
FOR EACH ROW 
begin
  SET NEW.total_pts=NEW.pts_1+NEW.pts_2+NEW.pts_3; 
  set NEW.old_pts=OLD.total_pts;
  IF NEW.total_pts>=0 THEN
    SET NEW.level='my_value';
  END IF;
end; //

delimiter ;
```